# How to return multiple documents of a code type (50 of each code)

Tags: sql

I need to return 50 documents of each code type. I currently can return the top 50 of a singular type but if I use "IN" and include mulitple that will only return top 50 of those together not individually. I'm still quite new to SQL and so I'm not sure of all the options I have. Top(50) works for one but I need this for multiple. I'm thinking I'll need some sort of subquery or maybe I can use count? I've tried those options but wasn't able to come up with any solutions after days of trying.

```
SELECT top (50) 
   c.num 
   cd.sequenceNum
   dc.Code, 
   d.DocPath
FROM tblDoc cd(nolock)
   inner join tblDocCode dc (nolock) 
         on cd.DocCodeID =dc.DocCodeID
   inner join tblc c (nolock)
         on cd.CID = c.CID
   inner join tblDoc d (nolock) 
         on cd.CDocID = d.TableID
WHERE DocCode in ('W2')
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL)? The syntax for this will vary. Figure SQL Server from the (nolock)?

Comment: On a side note: Are you voluntarily using the dangerous `nolock`, so you can get dirty reads? What makes this necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this. This is pretty standard. Just have an intermediate subquery than gives a row_number to each record by doc code and filter on less than or equal to 50 later on.

```
with all_docs as (
    SELECT
       c.num 
       cd.sequenceNum
       dc.Code, 
       d.DocPath,
       row_number() over ( partition by DocCode
                               order by 1 -- selects random
                                          -- if you want
                                          -- a precedence put it here.
                          ) as docCode_rn
    FROM tblDoc cd(nolock)
       inner join tblDocCode dc (nolock) 
             on cd.DocCodeID =dc.DocCodeID
       inner join tblc c (nolock)
             on cd.CID = c.CID
       inner join tblDoc d (nolock) 
             on cd.CDocID = d.TableID)
select * 
  from all_docs
 where docCode_rn <= 50
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand now that the row function captures each row and then the where statement filters how many rows you want. Amazing help and much appreciated! :)

Comment: @Seaquality Glad to hear it! It you are all set please accept the answer so other folks know they can move on.